# Sqlite , how select data after "case when"

Tags: sqlite

here is `MyTbl1`:

```
id (integer pk ai)
name (text char 25)
phone (int)
```

`MyTbl2`:

```
v1 (text char25)
v2 (text char 25)
```

i want make request like a:

```
select if exists id=1 in MyTbl1 if id=1 exists then select v1 from Mytbl2 if not exists return 0.
```

i try this:

```
select case when exists(select id from MyTbl1 where id=1) then (select v1 from MyTbl2) else 0 end;
```

its not working(

Comment: If the Id=1 does not exist in MyTbl1 do you want it to return no rows, or do you want it to return one row with a value of 0 instead of the v1 value ?

Comment: Formatting your question properly will help other to help you. I would consider editing your `sql` to make it easier to read.

Comment: if i do select id from MyTbl1 where id=1; and there is no id=1 sqlite return empty row, but i need 0. So i want make 1 request wich check if the id=1 exists in MyTbl1 , if exists then select v1 from MyTable2 if not exists - return 0

Answer (score 0):

use `where exists`

Also you will get all rows from MyTbl2 if there exists a row with id =` in the Mytbl1

```
select v1 from MyTbl2 t2
where exists 
( select 1 from MyTbl1 t1
  where t2.id =1
)
```

Comment: sorry i'm noob in sql)) i try make one construction of request like a: select if id=1 exists in t1 then select v2 from t2 else 0 - something like this. But i think its impossible)

Answer (score 0):

This query will bring back two values: v1 and id. 
But, id will be null if it is <>1 (since it will not come through the join clause)

```
select v1 , id
from MyTbl2 t2
left join MyTbl1 t1 on id =1
```

You can check if id is null and if it is, you can assume v1 is zero. This can be done as follows:

```
select case when id is null the 0 else v1 end
from MyTbl2 t2
left join MyTbl1 t1 on id =1
```